# How would I dump/load a .pgd file content into a postgres db

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a .pgd file I would like to use to create tables in a postgres db but am having trouble figuring out the command to load the contents of the file to create tables. The content of the file is shown below. Is there a simple command that would just run all these sql commands?

```
SET standard_conforming_strings = OFF;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."fires" CASCADE;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "public"."fires" (    "objectid" SERIAL,    CONSTRAINT "fires_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("objectid") );
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','fires','shape',4269,'POINT',2);
ALTER TABLE "fires" ALTER COLUMN "shape" SET NOT NULL;
CREATE INDEX "fires_shape_geom_idx" ON "public"."fires" USING GIST ("shape");
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fod_id" INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fpa_id" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "source_system_type" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "source_system" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "nwcg_reporting_agency" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "nwcg_reporting_unit_id" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "nwcg_reporting_unit_name" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "source_reporting_unit" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "source_reporting_unit_name" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "local_fire_report_id" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "local_incident_id" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fire_code" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fire_name" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "ics_209_incident_number" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "ics_209_name" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "mtbs_id" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "mtbs_fire_name" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "complex_name" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fire_year" INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "discovery_date" FLOAT8;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "discovery_doy" INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "discovery_time" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "stat_cause_code" FLOAT8;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "stat_cause_descr" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "cont_date" FLOAT8;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "cont_doy" INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "cont_time" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fire_size" FLOAT8;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fire_size_class" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "latitude" FLOAT8;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "longitude" FLOAT8;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "owner_code" FLOAT8;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "owner_descr" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "state" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "county" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fips_code" VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE "public"."fires" ADD COLUMN "fips_name" VARCHAR;
INSERT INTO "public"."fires" ("shape" , "objectid" , "fod_id", "fpa_id", "source_system_type", "source_system", "nwcg_reporting_agency", "nwcg_reporting_unit_id", "nwcg_reporting_unit_name", "source_reporting_unit", "source_reporting_unit_name", "local_fire_report_id", "local_incident_id", "fire_code", "fire_name", "fire_year", "discovery_date", "discovery_doy", "discovery_time", "stat_cause_code", "stat_cause_descr", "cont_date", "cont_doy", "cont_time", "fire_size",
```

Comment: `psql -f the_file.pgd`

Comment: And a link to the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE

Comment: I am getting a synatx error near psql

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: `psql` is a **command line** tool, it's not a "SQL command" that you can use in an arbitrary SQL client. You need to run it from the a command prompt (`bash`,  `cmd.exe`, ...) on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you already are connected to the database with the command line client `psql`, you can simply import the SQL script:

```
\i the_file.pgd
```